# What type of Speakers does IMAX use?

Tags: imax

I know that in 1988 they acquired a company named Sonics Associates. But all info on recent speakers setup I came across leads to a mixture of JBL and some other german-like brand I forgot it's name. Yet they clearly state they manufacture everything in-house. How so?

Comment: Haven't found a definitive answer yet - but [this](http://www.homecinemachoice.com/news/article/the-sound-of-imax/16250) states 'The loudspeakers, both the sub-bass and the full-range systems, are custom-designed and manufactured by IMAX' I'd call that 'politician-speak' for 'we don't make the drivers, but we do make the housings'.